# How to determine the force of a solenoid based on inductance

Tags: electromagnetism, inductor, solenoid, inductance

I'm looking to potentially build my own small solenoids, I thought perhaps that I could take an Air core inductor, a spring, piece of plastic, and conductive core and build my own. Is there a way to determine  force based on inductance and current (or power).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Force calculation:**

\$F=(N*I)^2\mu_0\dfrac{A}{(2g^2)}\$

Where:

\$\mu_0=4\pi*10^{-7}\$
\$F\$ is the force in Newtons
\$N\$ is the number of turns
\$I\$ is the current in Amps
\$A\$ is the area in length units squared
\$g\$ is the length of the gap between the solenoid and a piece of metal

From [this calculator](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Magnets/Solenoid-Force-Calculator.phtml)

**Inductance calculation:**

\$L=\dfrac{d^2*n^2}{18d+40l}\$

Where:

\$L\$ is inductance in micro Henrys
\$d\$ is coil diameter in inches
\$l\$ is coil length in inches
\$n\$ is number of turns.

From [this calculator](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Air-Core-Inductor-Calculator.phtml)

Comment: I have been searching all over and can't figure out what the gap g refers to. Is the "piece of metal" the plunger, or something the plunger runs into? Is the gap measured parallel to the direction of travel of the plunger, or perpendicular to it?

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic force 
F = \$ \Large -\frac{1}{2}i^2\frac{dL}{dx}   \$

Where *i* is current, *L* is inductance and *x* is plunger displacement